# What does ::before on its own line do in HTML?

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

This might be a stupid question, but if I have something like this:

```
<div id="topDiv">
  <header id="headerId" class="headerClass" style="display: block;">
    ::before
    <div>...</div>
    <div>...</div>
    <div>...</div>
  </header>
</div>
```

What does this 'before' in the html do?

I understand if I do the following in the CSS it adds these properties before every p element:  (this is from a [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_sel_before_style) example)

```
    p::before { 
      content: "Read this -";
      background-color: yellow;
      color: red;
      font-weight: bold;
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're seeing that `::before` because that is how your browser's developer tools represents a CSS `::before` pseudo-element in the document tree view.

If you literally had a string of text "::before" in your HTML file, it would do nothing special as it has no meaning in HTML; it would just show up as the text "::before" on your page.

Answer (score 1):

I guess there can be two reason (Its via personal experience & observation not a valid reference for support)

1) It provides a visual representation of these pseudo selectors according to their meaning
`::before` before the div to which its applied to and `::after` after the `div` to which its applied to

2) Pseudo selectors are used to insert some `content:''` in `HTML`. So this provides a distinct representation. User can easily inspect which content is inserted in `HTML` via these pseudos.

And Yes its on each browser how the implement and show the pseudos.

good luck!

Answer (score 1):

It is stating that you have a pseudo element in your html. Since it is not a 'real' element, you can't physically manipulate it like you can do with 'real' elements like div's and buttons.

You may also see `::after` appearing in places, representing somewhere for either your `id="headerId"` or `class="headerClass"` has a `::before` element declared.

the whole reason they are not declared like `<after></after>` or anything like this is because it is 'a ghost' or 'shadow' of a '**real element**', and hence can only be styled/manipulated in the css before the html is rendered.